# How do I use SUM in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I need to sum a group for my query. Something like:

```
SELECT customer_id, SUM(weekly) FROM earnings GROUP BY customer_id
```

The above works, but I need something a bit more complex, and my query is like this:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT SUM(weekly) FROM earnings) + 
    (SELECT SUM(day_earnings) FROM earnings) / .75
```

The above makes the sum of all the earnings, weekly and daily, but I need to group them by `customer_id like` in the first example. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the order of operations in your attempt above, it's the `SUM(day_earnings)` only that's divided by `.75`.  If it should be the weekly & day_earnings sums together, then put parentheses around them as `(SUM(weekly) + SUM(day_earnings)) / 0.75 AS earnings`.

```
SELECT 
  customer_id,
  customer_name,
  SUM(weekly) + SUM(day_earnings) / 0.75 AS earnings
FROM earnings JOIN customers ON earnings.customer_id = customers.customer_id
GROUP BY customer_id, customer_name
```

Comment: thanks! how can I also join that customer_id with the table customers to get the names? thank you!

Comment: See change above. `customer_name` added to select list and group by list, and joined in the FROM

Comment: excellent! thanks! please notice however that customer_id needs the table before it since it exists in both. Thanks for your help!

Comment: why you did not use of table name in the `sum()` ? I thought if I'm using `join` and `sum()` then I should use some thing like this: `sum(table.column)`, that is not correct ?

Comment: @Sajad The table name is only necessary if more than one table in the FROM has a column of the same name. Otherwise the column name can be used alone, just as it could in the plain `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
SELECT customer_id, SUM(weekly + (day_earnings / .75)) 
FROM earnings 
GROUP BY customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  customer_id, 
  SUM(weekly) weekly, 
  SUM(day_earnings) daily, 
  ((SUM(weekly) + SUM(day_earnings)) / .75) calc
FROM 
  earnings 
GROUP BY 
  customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do:

```
SELECT customer_id, (SUM(weekly) + SUM(day_earnings) / .75) AS earnSum FROM earnings GROUP BY customer_id
```